# How can I Localizing strings in code in WPF

Tags: wpf, localization

Basically, what do I have to do to Localize something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

So depending on the culture it should show `"Ciao", "Hola", "Bonjour"`, but this has to be done in the code, can't move it to the GUI.

I know how to localize the GUI (with `LocBaml`), but that doesn't work with what I need, but I can imagine is something similar to what `LocBaml` does (expect the part where it generates an assembly maybe). I just need a pinpoint in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are already localized using resource dictionaries, you can use just

```
MessageBox.Show((string)Application.Current.Resources["IDS_HELLO"]);
```

This approach has however a small disadvantage that the text won't change automatically if the application's language is changed *during* the `messagebox.Show`. (Mind that the dynamic localization requires anyway additional effort from your side.)